# How to iterate over a dataframe parsed with spaCy after it was saved as a csv?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, spacy

I created a data frame with spacy (columns: sentencens, tokens, stopwords, content words, pos, entities) and saved it as a csv.
When I read it as a csv file (it looks pretty decent), but when I perform a for loop over the columns, it does not return the expected result (for my basic domain of Python).

For example:

```
words = []
for items in df['tokens']:
    for word in items:
        words.append(word)
```

**what I expected**
[tea, and, ...]

**what I got**
['t',
'e',
'a',
',',
' ',
'a',
'n',
'd',
.
.
.

[image: dataframe image]
It happens in any column I try to iterate over. What is wrong with it?
I need it to be a csv as it is, to be shared with college mates that uses excel to visualize the data.

[image]

Comment: You need to show what the CSV file looks like or how you created it. It sounds like your tokens column is just a string and you're iterating over the characters.

Comment: Thank you polm23. I just added a picture of the current data frame. It looks like a list of characters but is string data type in fact.
What can I do so I can process it as a an actual list of character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from ast import literal_eval
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', converters={'tokens': literal_eval})

print(df.iloc[0,0][0])
```

This should help you evaluate the list of strings and then parse it out separately as needed. Then your for loop will work as above

Comment: It says that literal_eval is not defined.  (sorry, I am noob. And couldn't find a solution like a pack or module containing  'literal_eval' to install. So, hope you still can help me.

Comment: Added missing import, run the above code and you should be good, along with other imports (pandas)

Comment: @theflteacher : sounds good! I have been using stackoverflow for many years, make sure you also upvote and contribute when you get a chance. Keeps you sharp and contented that you are helping out! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I didn't had the minimum reproducible example. I created one:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
     { 'tokens': [['tea','and','coffee'],['coffee','with','milk']]})
```

[image]

```
words = []
for items in df['tokens']:
    for word in items:
        words.append(word)
```

[image]

Please show us your `df['tokens']` and give us a minimum reproducible example, I will edit accordingly.

Comment: I added an example of what happens when I peform the iteration.

Comment: Please show us `print(df['tokens'])`